# How can I create merged queries in Power BI Desktop that will allow for refreshable datasets/semantic models in Power BI Service?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am looking to reliably create queries in Power BI Desktop that will allow for scheduled refreshes of data. I have recently learned how to use both SQL Server and Web sources for data queries and have been able to create reports that are able to refresh on PBI Desktop, but when I publish those reports (and their underlying datasets/semantic models) to PBI Service, I am plagued by various errors that do not seem to have good underlying documentation on how to fix them.

For context, I am attempting to create reports that I can schedule to refresh (since the data is dynamic) and share them with my coworkers. I am under the impression that publishing my PBI Desktop reports to the PBI Service is the best way to do so.

The most current issue seems to be related to merging queries from two different Web sources. The verbatim error is:

> Data source error[Unable to combine data] Section1/[Query Name]/[Applied Step Name] references other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please rebuild this data combination.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface. Table: [Query Name].

My two queries are

ZdPaginatedTickets:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(https://[COMPANY NAME].zendesk.com/api/v2/search.json, [
    Query = [
        query = "created_at>"&DateTime.ToText(Date.StartOfYear(DateTime.LocalNow()), [Format = "yyyy-MM-dd"])&" tags:returns",
page = PageParam
    ]
])),
    count = {1..Number.RoundUp(Source[count]/100)},
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(count, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "fnZdTicketPagination", each fnZdTicketPagination([Column1])),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Invoked Custom Function",{"Column1"}),
    #"Expanded fnZdTicketPagination" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "fnZdTicketPagination", {"id", "created_at", "subject", "status", "requester_id", "tags", "custom_fields"}, {"id", "created_at", "subject", "status", "requester_id", "tags", "custom_fields"}),
    #"Expanded custom_fields" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded fnZdTicketPagination", "custom_fields"),
    #"Expanded custom_fields1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded custom_fields", "custom_fields", {"id", "value"}, {"id.1", "value"}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded custom_fields1", {"id.1"}, ZdTicketFields, {"id"}, "ZdTicketFields", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded ZdTicketFields" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "ZdTicketFields", {"title"}, {"ZdTicketFields.title"}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded ZdTicketFields",{"id.1"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns1", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns1"[ZdTicketFields.title]), "ZdTicketFields.title", "value"),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Location", "Total time spent (sec)", "Issue Type", "Contact Reasons", "Type of Ticket (Tag)", "Time spent last update (sec)"})
in
    #"Removed Columns2"
```

&

ZdTicketFields:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(https://[COMPANY NAME].zendesk.com/api/v2/ticket_fields)),
    ticket_fields = Source[ticket_fields],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(ticket_fields, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"url", "id", "type", "title", "raw_title", "description", "raw_description", "position", "active", "required", "collapsed_for_agents", "regexp_for_validation", "title_in_portal", "raw_title_in_portal", "visible_in_portal", "editable_in_portal", "required_in_portal", "tag", "created_at", "updated_at", "removable", "key", "agent_description"}, {"url", "id", "type", "title", "raw_title", "description", "raw_description", "position", "active", "required", "collapsed_for_agents", "regexp_for_validation", "title_in_portal", "raw_title_in_portal", "visible_in_portal", "editable_in_portal", "required_in_portal", "tag", "created_at", "updated_at", "removable", "key", "agent_description"})
in
    #"Expanded Column1"
```

EDIT: Full code from Advanced Editor for both queries above

When searching for solutions, I have attempted [using staging queries as described in this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20230406012933/https://excelguru.ca/power-query-errors-please-rebuild-this-data-combination/) but still ran into the same error message.

I additionally found this [solution regarding putting two sources into one query](https://web.archive.org/web/20220603015040/https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7161c2ed-4a8e-4cac-89c2-9105c70e204e/unable-to-combine-dataautoremovedcolumns1please-rebuild-this-data-combination?forum=powerquery) but haven't been able to get it to work since both sources require some transformations before merging.

I don't believe that this ask is impossible and I truly think that I am simply approaching this in the wrong way. What is the best method of accomplishing this?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: Sam's answer below works for my case! To add context for posterity:

The error I was receiving was due to an incredibly poorly documented feature of Power BI called "partitioning". I will not even pretend to have a full grasp of partitioning, and will direct those wishing to know more to [a video by Chris Webb](https://youtu.be/IQpniTiXQiI?t=2505).

TL;DR: Power BI will separate different queries and even different parts of the same query into different "partitions", and trying to merge across those partitions can cause the error I was receiving in PBI Service.

The reason I wasn't receiving any errors on PBI Desktop was because I had selected `Options > Global > Privacy > Privacy Levels > "Always ignore Privacy Level Settings"` which suppressed the issue. Once I turned that off, my query failed.

Comment: @horseyride thanks for the feedback. Both Queries work standalone. I have edited the question to include the full Advanced Editor code.

Comment: @horseyride the merge step is what is causing the issue.

Comment: @horseyride the first/"main" query is named ZdPaginatedTickets, the secondary query is ZdTicketFields

Comment: @horseyride I'm confused by your reply. Everything is merging and refreshing correctly in PBI Desktop, and I already have a step that has exactly what you wrote. When I publish this and try to refresh, PBI Service is giving me this error: `Data source error [Unable to combine data]`

Comment: You can ignore my comment. It was meant to say that what you want to do should be working. Maybe Sam has the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the privacy level of each connection in PBI Service. [Power BI Desktop privacy levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/desktop-privacy-levels).

As a test, you could select `Ignore the Privacy Levels and potentially improve performance` to see if that resolves the issue. If it does then you know this is the culprit. Then in PBI Service > Dataset > settings, under `Data source credentials`. Clear each one, and re-enter credentials and you'll see the privacy level option for each. Ensure these are set the same.

**Additionally**
You could try merging the two queries so that they are in the one query together:

```
let
    TF_Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(https://[COMPANY NAME].zendesk.com/api/v2/ticket_fields)), 
    ticket_fields = TF_Source[ticket_fields],
    #"TF Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(ticket_fields, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"TF Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"TF Converted to Table", "Column1", {"url", "id", "type", "title", "raw_title", "description", "raw_description", "position", "active", "required", "collapsed_for_agents", "regexp_for_validation", "title_in_portal", "raw_title_in_portal", "visible_in_portal", "editable_in_portal", "required_in_portal", "tag", "created_at", "updated_at", "removable", "key", "agent_description"}, {"url", "id", "type", "title", "raw_title", "description", "raw_description", "position", "active", "required", "collapsed_for_agents", "regexp_for_validation", "title_in_portal", "raw_title_in_portal", "visible_in_portal", "editable_in_portal", "required_in_portal", "tag", "created_at", "updated_at", "removable", "key", "agent_description"}),
    TICKET_FIELDS = #"TF Expanded Column1",

    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(https://[COMPANY NAME].zendesk.com/api/v2/search.json, [
    Query = [
        query = "created_at>"&DateTime.ToText(Date.StartOfYear(DateTime.LocalNow()), [Format = "yyyy-MM-dd"])&" tags:returns",
page = PageParam
    ]
])),
    count = {1..Number.RoundUp(Source[count]/100)},
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(count, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "fnZdTicketPagination", each fnZdTicketPagination([Column1])),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Invoked Custom Function",{"Column1"}),
    #"Expanded fnZdTicketPagination" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "fnZdTicketPagination", {"id", "created_at", "subject", "status", "requester_id", "tags", "custom_fields"}, {"id", "created_at", "subject", "status", "requester_id", "tags", "custom_fields"}),
    #"Expanded custom_fields" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded fnZdTicketPagination", "custom_fields"),
    #"Expanded custom_fields1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded custom_fields", "custom_fields", {"id", "value"}, {"id.1", "value"}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded custom_fields1", {"id.1"}, TICKET_FIELDS, {"id"}, "ZdTicketFields", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded ZdTicketFields" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "ZdTicketFields", {"title"}, {"ZdTicketFields.title"}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded ZdTicketFields",{"id.1"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns1", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns1"[ZdTicketFields.title]), "ZdTicketFields.title", "value"),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Location", "Total time spent (sec)", "Issue Type", "Contact Reasons", "Type of Ticket (Tag)", "Time spent last update (sec)"})
in
    #"Removed Columns2"
```

Comment: Here's the relevant doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/data-privacy-firewall

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft and Sam, thanks for your responses. I reviewed the documentation you both sent, but I'm not getting a `formula.firewall` error in either PBI Desktop or Service. Everything refreshes correctly in Desktop, but runs into a `Data source error[Unable to combine data]` error in the Service. I doubled-checked the privacy level option for each and they were both set to `Organizational`. As a test, I set both to `Public` and still ran into the same error.

Comment: Could you add the full code to your `ZdTicketFields` query to the question.

Comment: @SamNseir I've added the full code for both into the question. You were right that it _is_ indeed a `Formula.Firewall` issue, i just did not see it as such since I had `Always ignore Privacy Level Settings` selected, which removed the issue on Desktop

Comment: Please confirm that in Power BI portal, you cleared each Credential in the Dataset settings, and then re-created them, with both having the same Privacy Level. In the meantime, I will update the above answer with both queries merged into one.

Comment: I've updated the answer above with the two queries merged into one. If this doesn't work then please update the question to include the code for `fnZdTicketPagination` function.

Comment: @SamNseir This works! Thank you so much for help!